# Detect ETH transfer which made by smart contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I need to analyze blocks and txs to find if there is a transfer ETH to address from my list. When some user makes a direct transfer it is clear, I can check `to` parameter of the transaction. But sometimes users execute smart contracts which transfer ETH to address from my list, in this case `to` is the address of the smart contract, so I can't match it with my list. Is there a way to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like an "internal tx" of a forwarding contract like this [example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x89ea8c818170111f0b16ec1ba504acb72895e0807626a998f3bf78c6861150f7). Which does a value call (`address.call()()`). Then there is no way of knowing the final destination with tracing the transaction. Alternatively some contracts could emit an event or in the case of forwarding contracts, you could read the 'parentAddress' set during contract init.

Etherscan parses the trace for you so you can see those internal transfers afaik (see example above).

Comment: yes, this kind of internal txs when user interacts with smart contract and this smart contract makes eth transfer. interesting, how etherscan handles it :)

Comment: You can find some ways of decoding trace here -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions